# CSS Image Slider

Tags: javascript, html, css

Here is a link for the type of image slider I want. It is by W3schools but, they are using a big css file for that...i only want the relevant parts of it...I mean a css only for the image slider...do you guys know any link or something, not necessarily W3...but any site, from where i can have that ?

**Link**: http://www.w3schools.com/w3css/tryit.asp?filename=tryw3css_slideshow_self

Comment: you are using wrong link. this slideshow use w3 framework. go to http://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_js_slideshow this is manual js slideshow by w3 tutorials.

Comment: thank u :) this is what i was looking for

Answer (score 0):

The only part **w3 schools** uses CSS for is positioning the left and right buttons, try removing 
`<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://www.w3schools.com/lib/w3.css">` and run it again.

Comment: but i want the arrows :(

Comment: Its only used for positioning the arrows. The arrows just appear beneath the slider when you remove the CSS. You could also filter out the CSS rules which  apply to the buttons.

Answer (score 0):

you are using wrong link. this slideshow use w3 framework. go to [w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_js_slideshow](http://w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_js_slideshow) this is manual js slideshow by w3 tutorials

Answer (score 0):

Hello check out [this](https://gist.github.com/LocatelliPaolo/cb35cc4fefff4244f58e051795decd2a) and tell me if that sounds like what you wanted.
Online [demo](http://locatelli.altervista.org/slider-arrows/) of the code.